# Derive previous number from a revision string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

```
  #bash shell
  new="r.9.9.10.6.00999"
  new_ver=${new##*[!1-9]}; prefix=${new%%$new_ver}
  old=${prefix}$((new_ver-1))
  echo old=${old} ###prints old=r.9.9.10.6.00998
```

but don't work for:

```
  new="r.9.9.10.6.00100" #need to make old=r.9.9.10.6.00099
  new="r.9.9.10.6.01000" #need to make old=r.9.9.10.6.00999
```

because the `new_ver` becomes empty, what's the best way to get the previous version in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't your `${new##*[!1-9]}` really be `${new##*[!0-9]}`? Of course, I would just prefer something like `IFS=. read x x x x x new_ver <<<"${new}"`...

Comment: you are right, but `00999-1` didn't work as like `999-1`, also I didn't had to prefix 0's if I do `[!1-9]`, anyway it didn't work, I am using Steven Penny's solution now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is marginally less brittle than your solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "."} {$NF = sprintf("%0*d", length($NF), --$NF)} 1'
```

1. set input and output field separator to `.`
2. for each line, select last field
3. capture length of last field, so we can keep it the same
4. subtract 1 from value
5. set new value, making sure to prepend with correct number of `0` if needed
6. print modified line